# What happens if two people at the same time trying to buy same product with qty=1?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, onepage-checkout

I have bit confused about this. If there is a one product whose quantity = 1 and two customers
are trying to purchase it at the same time who can buy it? The person who starts the 
checkout first or who clicks on the `place order` button first? Or who pass the payment method first?

Any clarification on this will be appreciated.

Comment: the simplest way to find out is to try it. 2 browsers, 2 sessions 1 product.

Comment: @Marius : Great. I'll try on it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tested this in my localhost by using two different browsers. The result was `the person who clicks the 'place order' button first, only can buy the product. The other person will end up with an error message saying that 'qty for the requested product is not available'`

Answer (score 0):

The person, who starts checkout process first, can place the order.

The other person will see notification in cart: quantity not available or smth like that

Comment: man we need an extension for this! "Another customer just added this product too to basket. Be the first to checkout!" Makes it quite exhilarating to shop

Comment: Can you mention what is the exact native magento behaviour at this kind of situation.

Comment: @Stefan Gregori : Your answer should be corrected as `the person, who clicks the place order button first can place the order`

Comment: added to basket IS NOT the checkout process guys but everything following. my magento certification guide says it exactly as i mentioned, so i thought this should be right :-/

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that it should be possible to both order. This is millisecond timing though.

Normally, this will not happen. During the `placeOrder()`, the code to lower stock is called.  As far as my memory and your testing indicates anyway. It's not thread safe, but it's very tight timing and some luck.